# Setup environment for android NDK to run Cocos2d-X sample programs

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to run Cocos2d-X sample project for android in mac using eclipse, How to install android NDK in mac, What is the Procedure to setup native code in NDK.
Please reply asap.

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. In Run Configuration I dint enable target (To enable right click on project -> RunAs -> Run Configuration -> choose Target Tab, here Enable (Check box) Android virtual device Name.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote tutorial for set up cocos2d-x environment for android development.
Check [here](http://blog.webstarworks.com/2013/04/development-environment-preparation-for-porting-ios-game-made-using-the-cocos2d-framework-to-android-part-1).